SUMIF result not working and changes whenever columns are sorted on Google Sheets
I am using a sumif formula on google sheets
I have entered a =sumif formula in Tab B, to find the sum of the values in Column C in Tab A if the values in Column A in Tab A fulfills a certain criteria but the results I'm getting don't make sense.
The total sum of values are correct, but the individual sums for each of the criteria do not.
I can't attach the original google sheet because it's work stuff, but I copied the data into an excel sheet and posted pics
The formula I am using is
=SUMIF('Tab A'!$A:$A, $A$3, 'Tab A'!R2:R)
That formula entered in cell C3 on Tab B should find the sum of cells R4, R16, R24 & R32 from Tab A with a result of 288 (the sum of hours during Jan 2023 by School B students).
Instead the result I'm getting is 41.54, which is the sum of cells R49 and R25 (neither of which are connected to School B)
I have highlighted column C in Tab B to show the results I am getting with my formula against the results that I should be getting below
Tab A where the data is being take for the formula
Tab B where the formula is beibg enetered
Additionally, if I try to sort the data in Tab A by column A or B, the results change again
Appreciate any guidance!

I found the solution, had to change the formula to remove the heading row in column A:  =SUMIF('Tab A'!$A2:$A, $A$2, 'Tab A'!R2:R)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
